# React Checkbox not updating in functional component

Tags: reactjs

Here is my functional component: (**[Link to reproduce](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-colden-95qxl?file=/src/Checkbox.js)**)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Aux from "../../../../../../hoc/Auxilary/Auxilary";
const DropDownContainer = (props) =>
{
    const CheckedArray = Array(props.Data.length);
    for(let i = 0; i< CheckedArray.length; i++)
    CheckedArray[i] = false;
    const [Selected, setSelected] = useState({
        filterName: props.Name,
        filterObjects: props.Data,
        checked: CheckedArray.slice(),
        multiSelectAllowed: false,
    });
    const propsStructure = props.Data.map((elem, index) => (
        {
            title: elem,
            isSelected: false,
            id: index,
            key: "DropDown "+index,
            checkboxStyle: {
                width:"20%",
            },
            contentStyle: {

                width: "80%",


            }

        }
    
    ));

    const CheckBoxHandler = (index) =>
    {
        const newSelection = Selected;
        if(!Selected.multiSelectAllowed)
        {
            
            newSelection.checked.forEach((_,ind) => (newSelection.checked[ind] = false));
        }
            newSelection.checked[index] = !newSelection.checked[index];
        setSelected(newSelection);
        console.log(Selected.checked[index]);
        console.log(Selected.checked);

    }

    const PropDiv = propsStructure.map((elem) => {
        return <div className = "CheckBoxRow" key ={elem.key}>
                        <input 
                        style = {elem.checkboxStyle} type = "checkbox" checked = {Selected.checked[elem.id]}
                        onChange = {() => {CheckBoxHandler(elem.id)}}
                        />
                        <div style = {elem.contentStyle}>{elem.title}</div>
                </div>
    });

    return(
        <Aux>
                <div className = "Boxing">
                {PropDiv}
                </div>
        </Aux>
    );
}

export default DropDownContainer;

/*
from
props = ["a","b","c"]
to 

propsStructure = [
    {
        title:,
        isSelected:,
    }
]
*/
```

As per my code... when I print `Selected.checked` the value gets updated correctly. But it doesn't reflect in checkbox of the UI. As you can see here:
[image]

Can anyone point out the way to solve this? Here is the [link to reproduce](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-colden-95qxl?file=/src/Checkbox.js). As you can see in the console, the values are updating correctly but in my checkbox, it takes the initial value which is passed at the beginning which is false in this case and so despite me trying to check it, it always remains unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am change code .

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
const DropDownContainer = (props) => {
  const CheckedArray = Array(props.Data.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < CheckedArray.length; i++) CheckedArray[i] = false;
  const [Selected, setSelected] = useState({
    filterName: props.Name,
    filterObjects: props.Data,
    checked: CheckedArray.slice(),
    multiSelectAllowed: false
  });
  const propsStructure = props.Data.map((elem, index) => ({
    title: elem,
    isSelected: false,
    id: index,
    key: "DropDown " + index,
    checkboxStyle: {
      width: "20%"
    },
    contentStyle: {
      width: "80%"
    }
  }));

  const CheckBoxHandler = (index) => {
    let newSelection = { ...Selected };

    newSelection.checked[index] = !newSelection.checked[index];
    setSelected(newSelection);
    console.log(Selected.checked[index]);
    console.log(Selected.checked);
  };

  const PropDiv = propsStructure.map((elem) => {
    return (
      <div className="CheckBoxRow" key={elem.key}>
        <input
          style={elem.checkboxStyle}
          type="checkbox"
          checked={Selected.checked[elem.id]}
          onClick={() => {
            CheckBoxHandler(elem.id);
          }}
        />
        <div style={elem.contentStyle}>{elem.title}</div>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="Boxing">{PropDiv}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DropDownContainer;

/*
from
props = ["a","b","c"]
to 

propsStructure = [
    {
        title:,
        isSelected:,
    }
]
*/
```

**Working Demo:**

[image: CodeSandbox]

Comment: Tell me if there is a problem, otherwise do not forget the vote

Comment: This solution does work... just a quick question what change did you make exactly?

Comment: thanks.ok.change `onChange` to `onClick` .and change function `CheckBoxHandler`